# installing pybrain

Tags: python, git, pybrain

I am trying to install pybrain using :

```
git clone git://github.com/pybrain/pybrain.git
```

I installed git and then used windows command prompt to execute the above command. Everything goes well but when I open my python IDE, I cant import pybrain. The module doesn't exist. I wonder if I should've done something extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [PyBrain documentation](http://pybrain.org/docs/#installation), you're missing a second step, which is to install the code. So open a command prompt in the pybrain source directory (it'll have a `setup.py` file in it) and then run the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

For reference, more detailed installation instructions can be found at the [PyBrain Github wiki](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/wiki/installation)

Comment: that worked. The only problem now is that my eclipse doesnt still know about pybrain. import pybrain in my eclipse gives me an error. Do you have any suggestions how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you able to run the import from the Python interpreter? If so, then have you reloaded Eclipse since running the install command? Since it's Windows and you've just changed the PYTHONPATH environment variable, it's advisable to log out and log back in again to pick up the change if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. Solution for me was to call cmd.exe - "Run as administrator", when navigate into extracted pybrain sources folder in this console and finally run "setup.py install"

How when check, what pybrain is installed and available? Easy!
In console call python interpreter: for me it was

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

and after getting Python cli:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Type following line:

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
```

If no errors produced, when all is OK :)